# Hiding specific columns from 100% stacked when n < x in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a survey dataset for which I'm displaying a 100% stacked column visual with nationality on the x-axis and a legend breaking down survey responses into four categories. There are a number of slicers which allow the data to be broken down further by certain characteristics e.g. age, sex. What I would like to do is remove specific columns from the visual if there are fewer than x respondents represented in any of the individual nationalities. However, every method I try removes the sub-sections from the columns that are under x, rather than the entire column.

This is an example of how the data looks (without the personal characteristics):

| SurveyID | Country | ResponseText | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | France | Agree | 3 |
| ID2 | Germany | Disagree | 2 |
| ID3 | France | Strongly Agree | 4 |
| ID4 | Spain | Strongly Disagree | 1 |
| ID5 | Germany | Agree | 3 |
| ID6 | France | Disagree | 2 |
| ID7 | Germany | Strongly Agree | 4 |
| ID8 | France | Strongly Disagree | 1 |
| ID9 | Spain | Agree | 3 |
| ID10 | Germany | Disagree | 2 |
| ID11 | Germany | Agree | 3 |
| ID12 | France | Disagree | 2 |

[Here's a basic example of how the chart might look based on that data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWSFO.png) (Excel but the same principle).

I have tried measures based on counting the rows in various ways. For instance, something basic like this works fine for counting the rows if I just put the countries into a table along with the NationalityCount measure:

NationalityCount = COUNTA(SurveyData[SurveyID])

The problem arises when I try and use this as a filter on the graph by applying a greater than x filter, as that's when it calculates the NationalityCount by the subsections introduced by the legend. For instance, if x was 2 for the example data, it would remove all of those individual sub-categories since none of the sub-categories had more than 2 respondents within a country. What I want to happen in that scenario is that it removes Spain, since there were only 2 respondents, but leaves the entire France and Germany columns as they are, since there were 5 apiece.

Essentially, I want the n < x filter to be based on the count of the responses at the country (ie. whole column) level, not at the response level, but to still work within the confines of the slicers. I understand why it's doing what it's doing but I cannot figure out the correct way to make it total up the response for the country rather than the response categories within each country. I'm sure it's very simple, I'm just going round in circles at this stage! I read this response: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Hide-responses-in-visual-100-stacked-column-chart-where/td-p/1790612 but my question is basically what the original poster asked for in their response, which doesn't seem to have been answered.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Apologies, I tried to paste in my data and it kept forcing it to an image. I have amended now.